# Hook into amp-html runtime errors and display them

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible to hook into the error messages that are propagated from the AMP runtime. I would like to display these errors in an application.

Comment: There seems to be no mention of this in the AMP docs. Closes I can find is [AMPHTML errortracker](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/tools/errortracker) but not entirely sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @noogui Close but something in the runtime. If you run an AMP page and turn the `amp-debug=true` on, you will get runtime warning/error logs. I would like to display these warnings in something like a jsbin environment.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing error events to `amp-analytics` is actively being worked on https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/6415